# Django REST framework returns 400 error in test

Tags: python, django

```
FAIL: test_post (ecapp.tests.test_api.ProductApiTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lion-\Desktop\portfolio\ecapp\tests\test_api.py", line 82, in test_post
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 400 != 201
```

I get this Error when I run test below

test_api.py

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.test.client import encode_multipart
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
from faker import Faker
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, force_authenticate, APIClient, APITestCase

from ..models import Product
from ..views import ProductViewSet
from .factories import ProductFactory, UserFactory


class ProductApiTest(APITestCase):
    def test_post(self):
        user = UserFactory()
        view = ProductViewSet.as_view({'post': 'create'})
        filename = 'test_img'
        file = File(open('static/default_icon.jpg', 'rb'))
        uploaded_file = SimpleUploadedFile(
            filename, file.read(), content_type='multipart/form-data')
        client = APIClient()
        client.force_authenticate(user=user)
        data = {
            'name': 'test',
            'description': 'test',
            'price': 1,
            'amount': 1,
            'image': uploaded_file,
            'owner': 1
        }
        url = reverse('product-list')
        response = client.post(url, data, format='multipart')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Product.objects.count(), 1)
```

factories.py

```
import factory.fuzzy
import random
import datetime

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ('username',)

    email = factory.Sequence(lambda n: f'person{n}@example.com')
    username = factory.Faker('name')
    address = factory.Faker('address')
    icon = factory.Faker('image_url')
    message = factory.Faker('word')
    last_login_date = datetime.date.today()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions, authentication

from .models import Product, Sale
from .serializers import ProductSerializer

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """API endpoint"""
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'price',
                  'amount', 'image', 'owner', 'created_at')
```

Testing with the get method worked fine. Also, when I ran post on the browser, it worked.
Where should I modify to pass this test?

References

[How to generate a file upload (test) request with Django REST Framework's APIRequestFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453947/how-to-generate-a-file-upload-test-request-with-django-rest-frameworks-apireq)

[Official documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient)

Comment: What is in  `response.data` ?

Comment: When I checked response.data, I found that the 'image' field was invalid, so I fixed the filename and it worked.
Thank you very much.